# Discordance between the results of AsymptoticIntegrate and calculations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, asymptotics

Mathematica 11.3 finds

```
r = Integrate[Cos[k*(x^4 - x)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> k > 0]
```

> ```
> (1/(7680 k^(1/4)))
>   (-k^(9/2) Cos[π/8] Gamma[-(1/4)] 
>      HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {9/8, 5/4, 3/2, 13/8, 7/4}, -(k^6/4194304)] + 
>    480 k^(3/2)Gamma[-(1/4)] 
>      HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1/2, 5/8, 3/4, 9/8, 5/4}, -(k^6/4194304)] Sin[π/8] + 
>    160 Gamma[5/4] 
>      (96 Cos[π/8] 
>         HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {1/4, 3/8, 1/2, 3/4, 7/8}, -(k^6/4194304)] - 
>         k^3 HypergeometricPFQ[{}, {3/4, 7/8, 5/4, 11/8, 3/2}, -(k^6/4194304)] * 
>           Sin[π/8]))
> ```

Calculations confirm the above result:

```
r /. k -> 100.0000000000000000000
```

> ```
> -0.090 + 0.*10^-20 I
> ```

```
NIntegrate[Cos[100*(x^4 - x)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> -0.0903622
> ```

The expression `r` is not convenient to work with. For this reason, I try

```
as = 
  AsymptoticIntegrate[Cos[k*(x^4 - x)], 
    {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, Infinity, 4}] // Simplify
```

but the obtained result is doubtful in view of

```
N[as /. k -> 100, 15]
```

> ```
> 9.08651366206532*10^9 - 3.04523902051378*10^9 I
> ```

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to work with `r[k_ /; k > 0] := 
 Integrate[Cos[k*(x^4 - x)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] // Evaluate` ?

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Asymptotics is required: the expression r says nothing about its behavior as $k \to \infty$..

Comment: I didn't doubt about that. By the way , your result `-0.090+0.*10^-20` might be a hint to adapt the WorkingPrecision...

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you for your interest. AFAIK, the asymptotics can be obtained by the stationary-phase method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent).  The increase of WorkingPrecision does not help, producing the same result.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately my MMA version  is 11.0.1( Windows). Here the calculation of r gives wrong results for `k>~80`. Setting WorkingPrecision overcomes this problem.

Comment: @m_golderg: Thank you for your edit.

Comment: The error here is due to the behavior of the function `r[k]` near `k=100` where the rapid growth of the function in absolute value begins and the oscillation with a high frequency. Therefore, there is no chance for an asymptotic approximation.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: Please, pay your attention to  my above comment, where the stationary-phase method is referred to this end. It would be useful to implement it in Mathematica. In any case, no answer is better than an incorrect answer.

Comment: @user64494 Here we are dealing with numerical instability, so there is little chance of finding a good approximation.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: You are not right. The AsymptoticIntegrate command produces a wrong answer. One may try {k,Infinity,6} in as to this end. We deal with a bug.

Comment: @user64494 The integral `r[k]` diverges as `k` tends to infinity. In what sense do you want to construct an asymptotic approximation for it with respect to`k = Infinity`? This task seems to me incorrect.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Could you explain why you find r[k] diverges as k->infinity?  I tried substituting successively larger values of k (50, 100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, and 10000) into r[k], and found that, while r[k] oscillates wildly, the amplitude of its oscillations decreases monotonically, and appears to be approaching zero.  Sample calculation (here I've used "int" for r[k]): `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = \[Infinity]}, N[int /. k -> 10000, 10000]];
Accuracy[%]
NumberForm[%%, 10]`

Comment: @theorist You can not determine the limit poking a finger into the sky. The exact expression `r[k]` is known. Define the limit `r[k]`at `r->Infinity`. You can use an asymptotic expression `AsymptoticIntegrate[Cos[k*(x^4 - x)], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {k, Infinity, 4}] `